# Erratum for scientific articles

Tags: publications, errors-erratum, review-articles

I suspect that I have found a mistake in a scientific article (within the field of mathematics). Before bothering my colleagues with questions regarding the legitimacy of the content, I would like to know if anyone has corrected the (potential) error before me.

So the question is: Is there anywhere online, where I can find an erratum or similar for articles? Do I have to use specific keywords when searching for such content in databases? Or is it simply not possible to find easily?

Comment: Have you tried looking on Google (Scholar) for the name of the article and "erratum" or "corrigendum"? I don't know if things are different in mathematics, but if that search showed up nothing then I'd assume that the authors never corrected their mistake (or there was no mistake...).

Comment: @Ian_Fin: I did -- no luck. To clarify: I am looking for a general way of finding errata, e.g. an "errata database", that is independent of my specific problem at hand (which spawned the question).

Comment: This doesn't really help, of course, but for what it's worth I've encountered quite a few papers that call attention to errors in other papers. Sometimes this is immediately apparent, such as when one of the main results of the newer paper is to correct the earlier paper, and other times the error is buried in a footnote in the newer paper.

Comment: You can probably mail the Editor of the published article/journal. She can tell you about whether an errata was published earlier.

Answer (score 1):

If it's published in a journal you will usually get a hint right at the page of the paper that there is an erratum.

Comment: This assumes a journal that is online, mind you! But also, most of the times whatever search portal found the article will also bring up the errata, if they exist.

Comment: Are there still journals which aren't online available? In my field (chemistry) everything is online nowadays, even the most important journals from before 1960.